# Get newest file name into variable older than specific time

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to Linux, need a little help of you guys.

I want to get newest file name modified before a specific time into a variable.

I am able to get the result from below command. but I am getting file modification time and file name both.

```
find /home/administrator/ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -mmin +100 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 1
```

below is the output of above command

```
2018-09-10 18:39:18.3099856630 /home/administrator/K.sh
```

Desired output --> K.sh

how can I get filename only into a variable? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search the command “cut”

Comment: Why are you using the `printf....` ? `--mmin +100` should show you the files that are modified before the last 100 minutes.

Comment: @iamauser: i need to sort the files on basis of modification time from newer to older. i think sort command is using that time printed by printf command for sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using the -printf option of find command, you can get the last element of path (file name) by simply replacing all those formats with a '%f':

```
find /home/administrator/ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -mmin +100 -printf "%f\n"
```

You can append a regex pipeline at the end, if the results have to be sorted this way. It could be done in too many ways, here is an example with Perl:

```
find /home/administrator/ -not -path '*/\.*' -type f -mmin +100 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | sort -nr | head -n 1 | perl -lne 'print $1 if /.+\/(.+)/'
```

Comment: how can I further sort the list of files on basis of modification time?

Comment: @WannaBeSQLExpert Oops my bad. Edited in another solution

Comment: I am not allowed to use anything except shell. I can not use perl. can you suggest anything else?

Comment: @WannaBeSQLExpert You could probably take a look at @Stephen Darlington's answer right above. Both `sed` and `xargs` are quite standard in a Unix-like environment.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of options, a couple spring to mind:

- `... | sed 's/^.*\///'`
- `... | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs basename`

(I'm not familiar with the `printf` option. It's non-standard -- maybe GNU-only? -- and not available on the Mac.)